# How to send all WSL traffic through a proxy in host machine

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, routing, wsl2

I am using a SSH tunnel to connect to the internet on my host Windows machine. I am using proxifier to send all my traffic though port 1080 which is the proxy port. However, proxifier or selecting the proxy using windows "Proxy Settings" in settings menu doesn't seem to route WSL traffic though the proxy..

My question is how can I route WSL traffic through the proxy.

I also tried letting port 1080 though firewall (both inbound and outbound) and trying to send wsl data though proxychains to socks5 <host_IP> 1080. That didn't work either...

Comment: Some advice is found in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) and in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2122). There is also the [alpaca project](https://github.com/samuong/alpaca).

Comment: @harrymc I seem to be unable to connect to the socks5 proxy on my host for some reason. When I run sudo apt-get update it just hangs as [Connecting to 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5)]. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you looked at my links?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. Before I couldn't even get to wsl to even try to connect to the proxy on 192.168.1.5:80 (192.168.1.5 is the host machine for wsl). Now it tries to connect but hangs. I didn't try the alpaca project. I don't think it is what I am looking for. Both others suggest the same thing basically. Export the http_proxy variable to be 192.168.1.5:1080. It does what it is supposed to but it still doesn't connect to the proxy on host. Like I said in the previous comment, it hangs.

Comment: I have set the firewall rule to allow all incoming and outgoing traffic on that port. That is actually a socks5 proxy on 192.168.1.5:1080. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Try to create the tunnel not from the windows command prompt, but from the WSL command prompt. In windows, launch PowerShell, then type `wsl`, then create the tunnel, for example: `ssh -D 0.0.0.0:20000 USER@IP_ADDRESS`. In case of problem, disable temporarily the firewall.

Comment: @harrymc So you mean tunnel directly to the remote ssh server (not the host windows machine). The thing is I am using ssl/tls encryption and changing the SNI to bypass some ISP restrictions. Is there a command line tool for linux that will allow me to do that? Does the alpaca project support that functionality?

Comment: Surely SSH stuff you can do on Windows you can do also in Linux, if not better. You might be looking for mechanisms like [Proxies and Jump Hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts) or perhaps software like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

Comment: @harrymc HAProxy seems to have the functionality that I need. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The poster has indicated the the free
[HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
seems to have the needed functionality:

> HAProxy is a free, very fast and reliable solution offering high availability, load balancing, and proxying for TCP and HTTP-based applications. It is particularly suited for very high traffic web sites and powers quite a number of the world's most visited ones. Over the years it has become the de-facto standard opensource load balancer, is now shipped with most mainstream Linux distributions, and is often deployed by default in cloud platforms. Since it does not advertise itself, we only know it's used when the admins report it :-)

Comment: From reading about it, it seems to have the necessary functionality for an alternative way to achieve my ultimate goal which is to modify the SNI. However, I haven't tried it yet and by the reading that I have done about it, it doesn't technically answer the question. I will mark this as the answer after I try it. I hope that's OK with you.